# XAMPP directory shows when trying to upload file in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am learning Laravel and I am trying to upload multiple files.

I have a form that has some text and multiple file upload fields (Here is a piece of code, which I think is enough):

```
    {!! Form::open(['action' => 'OrdersController@store', 'method' => 'POST', 'files'=>'true']) !!}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('customer', 'კლიენტი')}}
        {{Form::text('customer', '', ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=> 'კლიენტის სახელი'])}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('date', 'თარიღი')}}
        {{ Form::date('date', 'none')}}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{Form::label('photo', 'ფოტოების ატვირთვა')}}
        {{Form::file('photo[]', ['class'=>'form-control', 'multiple'])}}
    </div>
```

And here is my store function in OrdersController:

```
    public function store(Request $request){
        $this->validate($request, [
        'customer'=>'required',
        'photo' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
        'date'=>'required',
         ]);


    return $request->file('photo');
    }
```

So when I tried to return this array, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvNr8.png) happened:

Can you explain what is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: an UploadedFile is an object, it has a `__toString` method that returns the path and filename .... so you are saying return the response with the location of this file as text ... also it isn't an array if it passed that validation

Comment: So this stuff really confused me because firstly an error was returned which said the image should be jpg, jpeg, etc... and then I tried to remove that validation, an error was not returned but the array is empty now